# Calculate percentage of up votes

Tags: php, math

I have searched this site and Google and even though the idea is pretty simple I can't figure it out.

I need to (like seen on YouTube) calculate the % of up-votes based on the amount up-votes and down-votes.

I have two vars, `$upvotes` and `$downvotes` now i need to calculate `$ratio`

For example

```
$upvotes = 3;
$downvotes = 1;
```

The ratio here needs to be 75 (%)

If you have

```
$upvotes = 0;
$downvotes = 100;
```

It needs to be 0 (%)

How do I calculate the percentage (in PHP)?

Comment: This question is guaranteed to result in a flood of identical answers due to the simple maths. :)

Comment: And most of them, being from PHP programmers, do not check the divisor for zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply

```
    if(($upvotes+$downvotes) != 0)
    $percentage = (float)($upvotes/($upvotes+$downvotes))*100;
    else
    $percentage = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it should be rather simple but i'm not good at this. Ill mark as correct when it allows me to.

Comment: @DRP96 added the checking condition for($upvotes+$downvotes)= 0.

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded my script to my server, try it here: http://drp-seiten.de/percentage.php?up=7&down=3

Answer (score 3):

Simple maths!

```
$ratio = $upvotes / ($upvotes + $downvotes) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($downvotes > 0 || $upvotes >0) {
$percentage = ($upvotes / ($upvotes+$downvotes));
}
elseif($upvotes > 0 && downvotes == 0) {
$percentage = 1;
}
$percentage = round(100*$percentage);

$percentage .= "%"; // if you want to add %
```

I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

`$percent = ( $upvotes / ( $upvotes + $downvotes ) ) * 100;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$percentage = (float) round((100 /($upvotes + $downvotes)) * $upvotes, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a round on it aswell, this will round the result to the closest integer.
eg. 75.5% = 76%;

```
$ratio = round((($upvotes/($upvotes+$downvotes))*100), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'%';
```